# Is there a way to explicitly tell the Postgres query planner that columns are dependent?

Tags: postgresql, query-planner

I have a two tables like this:
(My actual tables are different. I'm using these to simplify the problem.)

```
purchases (
  item_id,
  order_id,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id, order_id)
)
payments (
  item_id,
  order_id,
  payment_id
)
```

When I issue a query like this I get row estimates that are far too low because the query planner assumes item_id and order_id are independent:

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
JOIN purchases USING (item_id, order_id)
```

I can use a query like this to get around the issue:

```
SELECT *
FROM payments a
JOIN purchases b ON a.item_id || a.order_id = b.item_id || b.order_id
```

However, that causes other inefficiencies, and the query planner has less flexibility to reason about the query.

Another approach would be to introduce a generated column that concatenates the ids, but it would increase the table's space requirements if it is indexed and it would be equivalent to the prior approach if it were a virtual column.

Is there a way to tell the query planner that how to estimate cardinality on a group of columns without these tradeoffs?

Comment: Have you tried [multi column statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createstatistics.html)?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks! That is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. You've answered my question.

Comment: You should have an index on `payments(item_id, order_id)` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try *extended statistics* on both tables:

```
CREATE STATISTICS purchases_ext (dependencies)
   ON item_id, order_id FROM purchases;

ANALYZE purchases;

CREATE STATISTICS payments_ext (dependencies)
   ON item_id, order_id FROM payments;

ANALYZE payments;
```

Then the optimizer can add a correction factor to the estimate.